# Doing a Graph to highlight usefulness of twitter followers

Tags: math, twitter, graph, twitter-follow

I'm making a blog post about how if you follow TOO many people on twitter they end up becoming less useful (because you have too many tweets to go through/miss important updates).

So there's a direct correlation between the number of users you follow and how useful they become. If you follow too many the, the usefulness goes down, you need to find the right amount.

I'm trying to represent that in a graph vaguely (with no specific points)

I can imagine the graph having an X - with usefulness being Horizontal and No. of users you follow being Vertical. the sweet spot would therefore be in the middle.

Is this a good/correct way to represent what I'm trying to do? Could I potentially do it using a different graph type?

Comment: With the info you have given. this looks ok.. but are there other factors that determine usefulness?

Comment: Hi! Well, I'm just basing it right now on only the follow count. No other variables. 

I think the main trouble is, trying to explain this professionally T_T

Answer (score 0):

Would be more logical - at least in the Western world - to plot the friends count in X (horizontal) axis and the usefulness in Y (vertical) axis, I can see this in a line chart.

The chart would help readers get the idea, but I doubt you will be able to measure the "usefulness" in a relevant way.

Its value would also differ according to the profile of twitter friends: teenagers and niche professionals don't have the same usage of twitter and therefore do not publish the same volume of tweets. Therefore I would not use actual number of followers in the X axis, but instead only show "few followers" to the left, and "many friends" to the right.